# Random discrete values gneration for H2o Object in R

Tags: r, bigdata, h2o

I want to generate random discrete values for my H2o Object (3GB data) as  shown in the below example.

Example :

```
  C1    d_rand  d_status
1   0.886581278 1
2   0.117570381 0
3   0.824350102 1
4   0.356774692 0
5   0.995249866 1
```

I have written R-h2o code as below, However I am not able to get my result.

```
> rand_num <- h2o.runif(sample_3gb, seed = 123)
> sample_3gb$d_rand = rand_num
> sample_3gb$d_rand
H2OFrame with 9227049 rows and 1 column

First 10 rows:
       d_rand
1  0.06254423
2  0.15162557
3  0.18380040
4  0.66398323
5  0.92064923
6  0.54746199
7  0.45642585
8  0.69650692
9  0.54063600
10 0.77103990
> sample_3gb$d_status = 1
> sample_3gb$d_status[sample_3gb$d_rand <= 0.3] <- 0
Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, sample_3gb$d_rand <= 0.3, value = 0) : 
  `i` must be missing or a numeric vector
```

Below is are my H2o cluster details

```
R is connected to H2O cluster:
    H2O cluster uptime:         3 minutes 57 seconds 
    H2O cluster version:        3.0.0.30 
    H2O cluster name:           H2O_60331 
    H2O cluster total nodes:    2 
    H2O cluster total memory:   9.58 GB 
    H2O cluster total cores:    24 
    H2O cluster allowed cores:  24 
    H2O cluster healthy:        TRUE
```

I think this is happening with data type issue between R and H2o object i.e R is not reading the numeric values of h2o object as numeric. I am facing the same problem for some other conditional operations as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer my self..

```
> rand_num <- h2o.runif(sample_3gb, seed = 123)
> sample_3gb[,"status"] <- ifelse(rand_num > 0.3, 1, 0)
> sample_3gb[,"status"]
H2OFrame with 9227049 rows and 1 column

First 10 rows:
   status
1       0
2       0
3       0
4       1
5       1
6       1
7       1
8       1
9       1
10      1
```